# Arduino IDE documentation for WiFi.connected()

Tags: arduino-ide, wifi

I'm including this library "ESP8266WiFi.h" at the top of my sketch.
I can find documentation on `WiFiServer.available()`, but didn't find for `WiFi.connected()`, which is called in a server sketch after getting the client.

Clearly it's a test whether (once? I believe) the client is connected or not (and hasn't been explicitly closed in the server's side). It may seem obvious but some documented info would be helpful though.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find it defined in `WifiClient.h`. The version I am using is, in `WifiClient.cpp`:

```
uint8_t WiFiClient::connected() {
  if (!_client)
    return 0;
  return _client->state() == ESTABLISHED || available();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I will have to read the code thoroughly. Meanwhile I hope someone documents it...

Comment: Complain to the maintainers of the core. It's their responsibility.